Problem regarding Firestore security rules error of status code: PERMISSION_DENIED and the app on phone cannot retrieve documents okay in simulator
so I've published the following security rule
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /Users/{UserId} {
    allow read: if request.auth!=null && request.auth.uid == UserId;
    allow write: if request.auth !=null && request.auth.uid == UserId;
  }
}

When I tested this in the simulator, the read and write operations work as expected. When I go to my Flutter app and go to profile page, it returns an error and if I go to the logs I see:

W/Firestore(24658): (25.0.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(Users order by name);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

Please help because the rule is correct but a user is still locked out.
So I tried another rule which would achieve the same thing which is:
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Users/{UserId} {
    allow read: if request.auth!=null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
    allow write: if request.auth !=null && request.auth.uid == UserId;
  }
}

the simulator passes it but in the app I get the same error code.

Please edit the question to show the application code that doesn't work the way you expect.  Security rules by themselves don't mean anything - they must be paired with specific client queries to allow.  Your code should also explicitly verify that a user is signed in at the time of the query, and that the user's UID is exactly the same as the document ID being accessed.  I suggest printing a log with the current user's uid from the currentUser attribute of the user object.

Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.

During simulation you don't have to have a working app that can open said documents in real time it can't write a blank file if it don't have write permission
